# How can I override hash method for Laravel Auth?

Tags: laravel

I'm building a new project with Laravel but I'm forced to use an existing user database, which includes the password that is salted and hashed using a protocol that isn't bcrypt or argon.

Is it possible to override just the part of Laravel Auth that stores and retrieves the passowrd in the DB? I would love to use all of this package's functionality... it's just this one little thing that I need to tweak.

(Could I do it in the Eloquent model as a getter/setter, somehow?)

Comment: you can override the laravel default login and register function in logincontroller and registercontroller respectively.

Comment: In login controller under auth folder override the login method and in registercontroller override the create method

Comment: its not the part that retrieves the information that has to be adjusted, it is only the part that does the hash check would need to be adjusted

Answer (score 0):

there 2 possible way you can do.

1 - [Overide `LoginController` `authenticate`](https://medium.com/@simonhamp/why-and-how-to-override-laravel-s-built-in-auth-controller-methods-60f070897ac6) method

2 - Build your own custom driver
You may use build in [Hashing Class as refference](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Hashing.html)